# Chamar função passando campo

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Estou com uma função, que ao clicar no dropdownlist, ela verifica e muda a máscara de um campo:

```js
function HideTextBox(ddlId) {
  var ControlName = document.getElementById(ddlId.id);

  if (ControlName.value == 'P') //it depends on which value Selection do u want to hide or show your textbox 
  {
    document.getElementById('txtCpf').style.display = '';
    $("#txtCpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('txtCpf').style.display = '';

    $("#txtCpf").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
  }
}
```

Esse é o meu html:

```html
<div class="grid-1-3 margin-txt">
  <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Tipo de Pessoa:"></asp:Label>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIDType" runat="server" onchange="HideTextBox(this);" CssClass="form-control">
    <asp:ListItem Value="P">Física</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="L">Jurídica</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div class="grid-1-3  margin-txt">
  <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="CPF ou CNPJ"></asp:Label>
  <asp:TextBox ID="txtCpf" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="CPF ou CNPJ" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

Porém quando eu não seleciono o campo, ele não carrega a máscara, como posso chamar a função no load do form, passando o campo "ddlIDType" ? 
Eu tentei passando assim, porém ele me retorna erro:

```html
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "", "HideTextBox(" + ddlIDType.SelectedValue + ");", true);
```

Erro que está me retornando quando carrego a função dessa forma no load:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: HideTextBox is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primeira que fiz foi remover o `onchange="HideTextBox(this);"`.

Utilizando o `jquery`, busquei o elemento utilizando a seguinte notação `$("[id$='ddlIDType']")`, onde o `id$` que seria a forma de pegar o elemento desejado que termine com algo especificado.

Assim eu consigo definir uma *function* para o evento *change* do elemento: `.on('change', function () {`.

Para pegar o valor do *DropDownList* eu `$(this).val()` que seria basicamente a mesma coisa que fazer `$("[id$='ddlIDType']").val()`, mas como estou dentro da *function* que foi implementada para o evento do elemento, o *this* já representa esse elemento para o qual implementamos o evento.

```
<div class="grid-1-3 margin-txt">
    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Tipo de Pessoa:"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIDType" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
        <asp:ListItem Value="P">Física</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="L">Jurídica</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div class="grid-1-3  margin-txt">
    <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="CPF ou CNPJ"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCpf" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="CPF ou CNPJ" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        function Mascarar() {
            if ($("[id$='ddlIDType']").val() == 'P') {
                document.getElementById('txtCpf').style.display = '';
                $("#txtCpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
            } else {
                document.getElementById('txtCpf').style.display = '';

                $("#txtCpf").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
            }
        }

        Mascarar();

        $("[id$='ddlIDType']").on('change', function () {                
            Mascarar();
        })
    });
</script>
```

Para uma melhor compreensão, o código fonte está em meu [github](https://github.com/pablotdv/StackOverflow/tree/master/ChamarFuncaoPassandoCampo)

Comment: Dessa forma ele já funciona, que é clicando no ddlidtype ele altera a máscara, porém preciso pra quando ele realize o load do formulário, que ele venha com a máscara preenchida de pessoa física, que é o que não está ocorrendo.

Comment: Então, coloquei a chamada `$("#txtCpf").mask("999.999.999-99");` fora do evento, como primeira instrução a ser executada quando a pagina estiver carregada.

Comment: Mas quando o campo já vem preenchido com CNPJ, ele sempre carrega a máscara de CPF, ele só muda para CNPJ se eu altero no dropdownlist.

Comment: Eu encapsulei a lógica de mascara em uma function, vê se agora te ajuda

Comment: Dessa forma ele ficou somente na máscara do CNPJ, e ele tem q ser carregado conforme o dropdownlist, por isso eu queria q ele chamasse no load do formulário, pq se o txtid tivesse vazio, ele chamava a função da máscara CPF, senão ele carregava a do CNPJ.

Comment: Na realidade faltou eu pegar o valor do elemento, mas já editei a resposta

Comment: Agora sim Pablo rs, muito obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

Eu faço da seguinte forma:

```
 <select id="cbotipo" ClientIDMode="static" runat="server">
    <option value="1">Pessoa Jurídica</option> 
    <option value="2">Pessoa Física</option> 
</select>
```

ou

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="cbotipo" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static">
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Pessoa Jurídica</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">Pessoa Física</asp:ListItem>
```

E utilizo isto dentro o meu script (usando JQuery):

```
$("#txtcnpj").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
    $("#lblcnpj").text("CNPJ");

    $(function () {
        $("#cbotipo").change(function () {
            if ($("#cbotipo").val() == 2) {
                $("#txtcnpj").mask("999.999.999-99");
                $("#lblcnpj").text("CPF")
            } else {
                $("#txtcnpj").mask("99.999.999/9999-99");
                $("#lblcnpj").text("CNPJ");
            }
        });
    });
```

É **importante** ressaltar que para Javascript ou CSS (qualquer coisa no **lado cliente**), **é preciso utilizar** a tag **ClientIDMode="static"** quando se usar **campos** do **ASP.NET**

Comment: Na realidade não precisa definir o `ClientIDMode="static"`, só que você precisa pegar o elemento que termine com o id, assim `$("[id$='ddlIDType']")`.

Comment: Dessa forma ele funciona igual o meu já estava funcionando, eu preciso carregar a função no load do form, do seu jeito, ele sempre carrega a máscara de pessoa física no load, só muda se eu altero o ddlIDType