# Função onchange não funciona

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

Boa tarde, tenho uma função que verifica se o email digitado existe no banco, e se o email é valido. Segue a função:

```js
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  function validateEmail(emailField) {
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

    if (reg.test(emailField.value) == false) {
      alert('Email inválido.');
      emailField.value = '';
      return false;
    }
    document.getElementById("btnValidaEmail").click()
    return true;

  }

  </script>
```

Esse é o html do campo txtemail:

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" class="form-control" onChange="validateEmail(this);"></asp:TextBox>
```

O button Valida email:

```html
<asp:Button ID="btnValidaEmail" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display: none" OnClick="btnValidaEmail_Click" />
```

E a função que está no btnValidaEmail:

```js
clslogin pegaid = new clslogin();
SqlConnection conConexao3 = clsdb.AbreBanco();
if (txtid.Text != "") {
  clslogin log = new clslogin();
  SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT email from pessoa where email ='" + txtEmail.Text + "' and id != '" + txtid.Text + "'", conConexao3);

  SqlDataReader dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

  if (dr3.HasRows == true) {
    if (dr3.Read()) {
      veremail = true;
      txtEmail.Text = "";
      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email já existe em outro cadastro.');", true);
    }
  }
} else {
  clslogin log = new clslogin();
  SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT email from pessoa where email ='" + txtEmail.Text + "'", conConexao3);

  SqlDataReader dr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();

  if (dr3.HasRows == true) {
    if (dr3.Read()) {
      veremail = true;
      txtEmail.Text = "";
      ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Email já existe em outro cadastro.');", true);
    }
  }
}
```

Em um formulário que já possui o txtid, ela funciona perfeitamente, porém em um novo formulário sem dados, ao preencher o email ele só verifica se o email é valido, e não verifica se existe no sistema, ele nem chega entrar na função, coloquei um alert antes do if(txtid!=""), e nem no alert entrou, alguma ideia do que pode estar ocorrendo? Agradeço.

Comment: No caso, é como se não tivesse ativando o `document.getElementById("btnValidaEmail").click()`, é isso?

Comment: Acho que não é isso @ÐvÐ, ele está trabalhando com webforms e tentando pegar o evento onchange do componente textbox do webforms, só que é um pouco diferente no webforms o que ele quer fazer. Acredito que o que ela precisa seja isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/260810/5846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o jQuery fazer da seguinte forma para chamar o OnChange.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function validateEmail(emailField) {
        var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

        if (reg.test(emailField) == false) {
            alert('Email inválido.');
            emailField.value = '';
            return false;
        }
        $("[id$='btnValidaEmail']").click();
        return true;

    }

    $("[id$='txtEmail']").on('change', function () {
        validateEmail($(this).val());
    })
});
```

Outra coisa muito importando, mas relacionado ao seu código do seu botão para validar se o email já existe, **nunca utilize concatenação de string para montar as claúsulas SQL.** Se você utilizar concatenação, estará deixando seu sistema vulnerável a [SQL Injection](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL)

Reescri um exemplo da sua validação utilizando a opção de passagem de parâmetros na instruação *select*

```
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT email from pessoa where email = @email and id != @id", conConexao3);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtid.Text);
```

No meu [github](https://github.com/pablotdv/StackOverflow/tree/master/FuncaoOnChange) você pode ver o exemplo do código que montei para a resposta.

Comment: Não funcionou desta forma, ele valida o email, mas não está entrando na função que está no btnValidaEmail, de forma nenhuma agora.

Comment: Fiz uma alteração na forma de chamar o click do botão usando jquery

Comment: Alterei e continua com o mesmo problema, ele não está entrando no click do button.

Comment: Qualquer email que eu digito, mesmo válido ou não ele exibi o Alerta de email inválido.

Comment: Com relação a validação do email a chamada por jquery já passo o valor do email, e não vi que tinha um emailField.value, mas alterei isso na resposta, agora estou tentando achar uma forma de chamar o click do botão

Comment: Acredito que era só isso o problema, adicionei no meu github o exemplo que montei.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado.